# What does equal to operator in ="XXXX" do in SSIS derived column when exporting into CSV file

Tags: ssis, transformation

I received an SSIS package that was built by someone else. In one of the control folow that gets the data from oledb data source and puts it into a csv file. Their is a derived column between the oledb data source task and the flat file destination task.
[image: Data flow task]

The derived data flow task creates some new columns with some of the expression having an equal to sign.
[image: derived column]

These columns are then redirected to CSV file. This file is again read by another data flow task that reads this created CSV file. If I remove the = sign from the derived column it gives me an error while reading the flat file.

> [Flat File Source [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqqyI.png)] Error: The column delimiter for column "CompanyCode" was not found.

The data type of column company code is varchar.

My Question:

What is the = sign in the derived column task used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equals sign is a string literal in the expression.

If your data had a row where the value of `CompanyCode` was

> ABC

Then the derived column `CompanyCodeWithZero` would contain

> ="ABC"

I can't surmise why removing the equal sign results in the error you are getting since it seems to be coming from some other part of the package not described in your question (Flat File Source 2).

Answer (score 1):

The error message you provided

> [Flat File Source 2] Error: The column delimiter for column "CompanyCode" was not found.

Is showing that it has no relation with the derived column transformation, it is thrown by `[Flat File Source 2]` and it occur when the flat file used doesn't matches the settings used in the `Flat File Connection manager`, check that this file does not contains rows with a corrupted structure.

And about the **equal sign** (`=`) (like @TabAlleman said)

**The equals sign is a string literal in the expression.**